# How to get a user role of a specific blog in multisite?

Tags: multisite, user-roles

How can we get a user's role of a specific site on a Multisite network?

Let's say the user is a subscriber on the parent site and admin of his own subdomain. Is there a way to only return the role on the parent site or by a specific blog id?

Ex: `get_wpmu_user_role($user_id, $blog_id);`

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 8):

You can use either [`WP_User`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User):

```
$wp_user_obj = new WP_User(
    // $user_id
    get_current_user_id(),
    // $name | login, ignored if $user_id is set
    '',
    // $blog_id
    get_current_blog_id()
);
```

Or [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users):

```
$get_users_obj = get_users(
    array(
        'blog_id' => get_current_blog_id(),
        'search'  => get_current_user_id()
    )
);
```

As they are both `blog_id` perceptive, if you provide it.

The former will return a `WP_User` object, the roles are accessible like this:

```
// array of roles
$wp_user_obj->roles
// access the first or only 
$wp_user_obj->roles[0]
```

The latter will returns an array of `WP_User` objects, actually only one object, because the search for a `user_id` can only return one unique object, the roles are accessible like this:

```
// array of roles
$get_users_obj[0]->roles
// access the first or only 
$get_users_obj[0]->roles[0]
```

Another idea, never done that myself, but if you have some kind of shared login and want the information of the current user, then this could work too:

```
switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
$current_user_at_different_blog = wp_get_current_user();
restore_current_blog();
```

`wp_get_current_user()` does return a `WP_User` object, so the information is accessible like:

```
// array of roles
$current_user_at_different_blog->roles
// access the first or only 
$current_user_at_different_blog->roles[0]
```

Last but not least, there is [`current_user_can_for_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can_for_blog) which can be used like this:

```
current_user_can_for_blog( $blog_id, $capability );
```

The codex page states:

> Whether current user has a capability or role for a given blog.

But I *strongly* suspect like [`current_user_can()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) it [shouldn't be used for roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Notes), but capability checks are power- and useful too.

Comment: Thank you so much! This detailed explanation is fabulous. This code here worked for me:

`$get_users_obj = get_users(array( 'blog_id' => get_current_blog_id(),'search'  => get_current_user_id() )
);
$user_roles = $get_users_obj[0]->roles[0];`

However, I want to mention that I received two PHP notices "Undefined offset: 0" and "Trying to get property of non-object" when using this snippet... Any suggestions on the best way to resolve this?